# SQL group rows by condition

Tags: sql, db2, match, case

I need to merge 3 rows into one with following condition - if at least one J exists in any of the columns then  all columns should be overwritten with J. If there are all N I should get one row with all N.

I am thiking something like -

```
SELECT BRGNR
, AFTLST
,CASE WHEN EGMK IN ('J','N') THEN 'J' ELSE EGMK END EGMK
,CASE WHEN TDMK IN ('J','N') THEN 'J' ELSE TDMK END TDMK
,CASE WHEN UDMK IN ('J','N') THEN 'J' ELSE UDMK END UDMK
, CASE WHEN FUMK IN ('J','N') THEN 'J' ELSE FUMK END FUMK
  FROM IF.TIF_BRUGER_BT  
GROUP BY BRGNR
```

But the problem is then in that case when I have all N all values will be overwritten to J anyway, and I need to have N if all values are N

[image: Original result]

Comment: can you post your sample dataset  and expected output.

Comment: We love that you're here and we need to see your code so we can help.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. You should provide the input data (I guess that's the screen shot) and the expected output from that input. Please **[edit]** your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to interpret the question as:

- If a there is a `'J'` in a column, then result is `'J'`.
- Otherwise, if all are `'N'`, then result in `'N'`.

I will assume that the only values are `'J'` and `'N'`.  My guess is that `'J'` --> "yes" and `'N'` --> "no" and you want "yes" if any value is "yes".

If so, you can use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT BRGNR, AFTLST,
       MIN(EGMK), MIN(TDMK), MIN(UDMK), MIN(FUMK)
FROM IF.TIF_BRUGER_BT  
GROUP BY BRGNR, AFTLST
```